# How to pass two RenderBuffers into one RenderTexture?

Tags: unity, depth-buffer, rendertexture, unity-urp

I have a Unity URP project and in the Scriptable Render Pipeline, I would like to create a `RenderTexture` and pass the depth and color buffer of the camera object as the color and depth buffer of this `RenderTexture` object. Unfortunately, these buffers only have a getter, so I suppose only copy / blit operations would solve my problem. However I don't wanna copy, just pass the references. Is there a way I can achieve this?

I want to process the depth and color buffer of the camera in one shader call, but now I need to do it in two steps.

In the shader, I would process both of them like this:

```
float4 frag(v2f i, out float depth : SV_Depth) : SV_Target
{
    float scale = 2.0;
    float3 color = Rcas(i.uv, scale);
 
    depth = SAMPLE_DEPTH_TEXTURE(_MainTex, i.uv);
    return float4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: This looks like something to implement as a [Render Feature](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@17.0/manual/renderer-features/create-custom-renderer-feature.html) in the Scriptable Render Pipeline. This lets you inject a full-screen pass between the camera rendering the scene and when the result gets shown on the screen, using Unity's internal pool of buffers for reading/writing colours/depths instead of managing your own. [I show an example here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/183517/39518), though the exact steps may have changed as URP has matured.

Comment: Putting the camera's existing render buffers into a RenderTexture without a copy doesn't make sense, because while it's reading from that buffer, where would the camera write to? But using a Render Feature, Unity can ping-pong between its internal buffers, reading from one to write to the other, without a copy in between. Whichever member of the ping-pong pair it writes to last becomes the output.